# How to create random string using user-inputted characters (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, random

My code looks like this:

```
char = input('Characters: ')
length = int(input('Length: '))
```

I want to make a `length` long string which uses randomly selected characters from the `char` variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose 1 random character for `length` times.
Here are some potential answers:
With for loops:

```py
import random

chars = input("Characters: ")
length = int(input("Length: "))
result = ''
for _ in range(length):
    result += random.choice(chars)
```

or
with list comps:

```py
import random

chars = input("Characters: ")
length = int(input("Length: "))
result = ''.join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length)])
```

You'll get the random string in `result`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use choice from random library

```
import random
char = input('Characters: ')
list_array = [char for char in char]
length = int(input('Length: '))

my_str = ""
for i in range(length):
    my_str += random.choice(char)
print(my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the same character can appear several times in `char` but that the probability with which this character can appear in the generated string should be the same as for any other character, I would suggest to convert the inputted character string to a set (for uniqueness), then to a list, and then use the `choice` function from the `random` module in a loop for the desired number of times:

```
from random import choice
char = input('Characters: ')
char_list = list(set(char))
generated_string = ""
length = int(input('Length: '))
for i in range(length):
    generated_string += choice(char_list)
print(generated_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

In one line, without the need for any for loop

```
import random
mylongstring=''.join(random.choices(char, k=length)) # If non-unique sampling is needed
mylongstring=''.join(random.sample(char, k=length)) # If Unique elements from string are required
```

## Explanation

You can use `random.choices` with `k` equal to you string length. It extracts randomly `k` elements from your generating iterable element (and string is naturally a sequence of characters). Then you can `join` your new list.
If you use `random.sample` instead, the sampling is performed uniquely (each character is extracted only once from your `char`)

The code is here (note that I fixed char and length just for easy testing purposes)

```
char = 'mystring'
length =  20

import random
mylonglist = random.choices(char, k=length)
mylongstring=''.join(mylonglist)

print(mylongstring)

# result printed: isngmgstssyinismnsrt

# for unique sampling
length=5
mylonglist = random.sample(char, k=length)
mylongstring=''.join(mylonglist)
print(mylongstring)
# printed: irtgs
```

Here you find the doc for [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and for [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra imports and using the fact that `set` "unorders" the collection.

```
chars = input('Characters: ')
length = int(input('Length: '))


random_str = ''.join(c for _, c in set(enumerate(chars)))[:length])
```

Notice: at each execution the `random_str` will be different and its result cannot be predicted. This could be annoying in a testing phase. Instead, if using for example `random.choice` you should first fix the "randomness" by setting the `random.seed(n)` so, the result at each execution will be the same.

Comment: Note that set order is not random but arbitrary. This would not work on PyPy, for example.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi good point for the compiler dependency. `random` generates pseudo-random numbers... so what is the difference between  with random and arbitrary?

Comment: "arbitrary order" means the standard does not define it - any implementation can choose one (or several!) as it sees fit. This may *look* random if one does not know how the implementation works but it is not. Check out the order of a set of consecutive integers - e.g. `set(range(8))` - and even for CPython it should be apparent that sets do not necessarily randomize order.

Answer (score -1):

Within the module `random` in `numpy`, the `choice` function allows you to manage the cases *with* and *without* replacement (in simple words, can the characters in `char` string be picked more than or only once?):

```
import numpy as np

my_string = "hello"

print(np.random.choice(list(my_string), 3, replace=False))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
lol
```

Note that, if `replace=True`, you can only request for a number of characters **not greater than** the length of `my_string`, otherwise a `ValueError` will be thrown:

```
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```